# Using reframe.js with HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the reframe.js plugin on a page with HTML5 embedded video, but I cant get this to work.

It works fine if I use an iframe with a link to a YouTube video, but if I add my own video file that is within the same folder, this doesnt work at all.

The page works, the video loads and plays, but the video is a fixed size and is not resized by reframe.js

This is my bare bones html page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Reframe.js Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<video controls style="width:640px;height:480px;" poster="poster.png" preload="auto">
<source src="test.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
<source src="test.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>

<script type="text/javascript" src="reframe.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
reframe('video');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I replace the  section with iframe code showing a YouTube video, then it works fine!

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6FQsIfE7sZM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this question and has the same problem, I have now found a solution.

I removed the specific height and width from the  tag, wrapped the video in a wrapper div container, and then applied reframe.js to the container.

The final video code is as follows:

```
<div id="video-container">
<video controls width="100%" height="100%" poster="poster.png" preload="auto">
<source src="test.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
<source src="test.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
</div>
```

And then:

```
reframe('#video-container');
```

And this now works.